Looking for a user-friendly way of bulk adding new keywords to a multiple-selection field, but without overwriting existing keywords
Basically, I'd like to take a list of items that already have tags applied to them like this:



Item
Keywords




Item 1
red, blue, green


Item 2
red


Item 3
blue, orange, purple


Item 4
green



The let the user select as many items as they want and append a new keyword to all of them in one action, like this:



Item
Keywords




Item 1
red, blue, green, ORANGE


Item 2
red


Item 3
blue, purple, ORANGE


Item 4
green, ORANGE



Right now, if they select multiple items and edit them at the same time, it overwrites any existing keywords, so the existing selections would be lost. It would be unrealistic to add the new keyword to each item one-by-one with the amount of things we want to tag.
I've been trying to figure this out with a managed metadata column, but even a choice column would work. I have found ways of doing this in the classic experience (datasheet view) or with powershell, but I'd like to come up with a friendlier way of doing this that wouldn't require the user to leave the modern SharePoint UI.
Thanks for any ideas! This has been weirdly hard to figure out for something that is a pretty obvious need for any user who is updating metadata.

If you're familiar with SPFx, then Listview Command Extension would be a good option for users to select multiple items and provide the new value to update the selected items by appending new value to the existing values of a multi-select choice field

Here are the steps and the main code blocks in SPFx ListView Command Extension to complete this bulk update (updating multi-select column by adding new value to the existing values). Please the screenshots as well.
Steps

Show [Update Items] command button in the list/library command bar when one
or more items are selected
Implement Click Event of [Update Items]  to show a dialog for user to
choose a new value from a dropdown (fluentui/react) control. For now, dropdown options are hard-coded in the code. But can be retrieved from the source as well.
User then click on the [Update Multi-Choice Field] button on the dialog to update the selected items metadata.




DialogDemoCommandSet.ts
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseListViewCommandSet,
  type Command,
  type IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters,
  type ListViewStateChangedEventArgs
} from '@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility';
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';

import MyDialog, { IMultiChoiceItem } from './myDialogDemo';

import { spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";

/**
 * If your command set uses the ClientSideComponentProperties JSON input,
 * it will be deserialized into the BaseExtension.properties object.
 * You can define an interface to describe it.
 */
export interface IDialogDemoCommandSetProperties {
  // This is an example; replace with your own properties
  sampleTextOne: string;
  sampleTextTwo: string;
}

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'DialogDemoCommandSet';

export default class DialogDemoCommandSet extends BaseListViewCommandSet<IDialogDemoCommandSetProperties> {

  public sp: any = null;

  public onInit(): Promise<void> {

    //initialize pnp context from the current context
    this.sp = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context));

    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Initialized DialogDemoCommandSet');

    // initial state of the command's visibility
    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    compareOneCommand.visible = false;

    const compareOneCommand2: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');
    compareOneCommand2.visible = false;

    this.context.listView.listViewStateChangedEvent.add(this, this._onListViewStateChanged);

    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {

    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':

        Dialog.alert(`${this.properties.sampleTextOne}`).catch(() => {
          // /* handle error */
        });

        break;
      case 'COMMAND_2':

        const itemChoicesArray: IMultiChoiceItem[] = [];

        //get the values of the selected rows
        //console.log(event.selectedRows);

        //get selected items fields' values and pass to the downstream dialog component
        let selectedRowsObj = event.selectedRows;

        if (selectedRowsObj.length > 0) {

          let selectItemIDs: number[] = [];
          let selectedItemChoices: any[] = [];

          selectedRowsObj.forEach(element => {

            selectItemIDs.push(element.getValueByName('ID'));
            selectedItemChoices.push(element.getValueByName('MultiSelectChoice'));

            let obj: IMultiChoiceItem = {
              itemId: element.getValueByName('ID'),
              choiceValues: element.getValueByName('MultiSelectChoice')
            }

            itemChoicesArray.push(obj);

          });

          //Initialize and show dialog
          const dialog: MyDialog = new MyDialog();
          dialog.message = "Updating multi-select choice column";
          dialog.listName = this.context.listView.list?.title as string;
          dialog.listUrl = this.context.listView.list?.serverRelativeUrl as string;
          dialog.selectedRowValues = itemChoicesArray;
          dialog.spContext = this.sp;

          dialog.show();
        }
        else {

          Dialog.alert("Select one or more items to update").catch(() => {
            /* handle error */
          });

        }

        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
  }

  private _onListViewStateChanged = (args: ListViewStateChangedEventArgs): void => {

    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'List view state changed');

    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    if (compareOneCommand) {
      // This command should be hidden unless exactly one row is selected.
      compareOneCommand.visible = this.context.listView.selectedRows?.length === 1;
    }

    const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');

    if (compareTwoCommand) {

      compareTwoCommand.visible = (this.context.listView.selectedRows != null);
    }



    //Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, compareOneCommand2.visible ? "Visible" : "Not Visible");
    console.log(compareTwoCommand.visible ? "Visible" : "Not Visible")

    // TODO: Add your logic here
    // You should call this.raiseOnChage() to update the command bar
    this.raiseOnChange();
  }
}


myDialogDemo.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BaseDialog, IDialogConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';
import { PrimaryButton, Dropdown, IDropdownOption, Label, TextField } from '@fluentui/react';
import { DialogFooter, DialogContent } from '@fluentui/react';

// import { spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";
// import "@pnp/sp/webs";
// import "@pnp/sp/lists";
// import "@pnp/sp/items";


interface ImyDialogContentProps {
    message: string;
    close: () => void;
    itemIds?: string[];
    listName: string;
    listUrl: string;
    spContext: any;
    selectedRowValues: IMultiChoiceItem[];
}

interface ImyDialogContentState {
    docTitle: string;
    docStatus: string;
    subText: string;
    selectedItem?: IDropdownOption;
}

export interface IMultiChoiceItem {
    itemId: number;
    choiceValues: string[]
}

const mydropdownControllChoice = [

    { key: 'banana', text: 'Banana' },
    { key: 'orange', text: 'Orange' },
    { key: 'grape', text: 'Grape' },
    { key: 'strawberry', text: 'Strawberry' },
    { key: 'coconut', text: 'Coconut' },
    { key: 'blueberry', text: 'Blueberry' },
    { key: 'dates', text: 'Dates' },
    { key: 'watermelon', text: 'Watermelon' },

];


//const itemChoicesArray: IMultiChoiceItem[] = [];

class MyDialogContent extends React.Component<ImyDialogContentProps, ImyDialogContentState, {}> {

    // private _sentValue: string;


    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        // Default Color
        //this._sentValue = "my Value";
        this.state = {
            docTitle: this.props.listName,
            docStatus: "Pending",
            subText: this.props.message
        }

        this.onFruitDropdownChange = this.onFruitDropdownChange.bind(this);
        this.SaveData = this.SaveData.bind(this);
    }

    private onFruitDropdownChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>, sitem: IDropdownOption): void => {
        this.setState({ selectedItem: sitem })
    };

    private async SaveData(): Promise<void> {

        console.log("Logging List Name and Url");
        console.log(this.props.listName + " - " + this.props.listUrl);
        console.log("Logging User Selected Values");
        console.log(this.props.selectedRowValues);

        this.setState({ subText: "Please type a Choice value to updated selected items" });

        const list = await this.props.spContext.web.lists.getByTitle(`${this.props.listName}`);

        this.props.selectedRowValues.forEach((item: IMultiChoiceItem) => {

            this.setState({ subText: `Updating Item: "${item.itemId}"` });

            if (item) {

                if (item.choiceValues.length > 0) {
                    if (item.choiceValues.join(";").search(this.state.selectedItem?.text as string) == -1) {
                        item.choiceValues.push(this.state.selectedItem?.text as string);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    let myArray: string[] = [];
                    myArray.push(this.state.selectedItem?.text as string);
                    item.choiceValues = myArray;
                }

                const i = list.items.getById(item.itemId).update({
                    MultiSelectChoice: item.choiceValues
                });

                console.log(i);

                this.setState({ subText: `Completed Updating Item: ${item.itemId}` });
            }
        });
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <DialogContent
            title='Save Document Data?'
            subText={this.state.subText}
            onDismiss={this.props.close}
            showCloseButton={true}
        >
            <p>User must select one or more items from the library/list
                and then click <strong>Update Items</strong> in the command bar to dialog to show up</p>

            <Dropdown
                label="Bulk Item Update Example"
                selectedKey={this.state.selectedItem ? this.state.selectedItem.key : undefined}
                placeholder="Select an option"
                options={mydropdownControllChoice.sort()}
                onChange={this.onFruitDropdownChange}
            />

            <Label>List/Document Library Name</Label>
            <TextField placeholder='Enter Documnet Title'
                value={this.state.docTitle}
                onChange={(event: any, val: string) => { this.setState({ docTitle: val }) }}
                disabled={true}
            />

            <Label>Approval Status</Label>
            <TextField placeholder='Enter Status'
                value={this.state.docStatus}
                onChange={(event: any, val: string) => { this.setState({ docStatus: val }) }}
                disabled={true}
            />

            <DialogFooter>

                <PrimaryButton text='Cancel' title='Cancel' onClick={this.props.close} />
                <PrimaryButton text='Update Multi Choice Field' title='Update Multi Choice Field' onClick={this.SaveData} />

            </DialogFooter>

        </DialogContent>;
    }

}


export default class MyDialog extends BaseDialog {

    public listName: string = "";
    public listUrl: string = "";
    public selectedRowValues: IMultiChoiceItem[];
    public spContext: any;

    public message: string = "";

    public render(): void {
        ReactDOM.render(<MyDialogContent
            close={this.close}
            message={this.message}
            itemIds={this.message.split(";")}
            listName={this.listName}
            listUrl={this.listUrl}
            selectedRowValues={this.selectedRowValues}
            spContext={this.spContext}

        />, this.domElement);
    }

    public getConfig(): IDialogConfiguration {

        return { isBlocking: false };
    }

    protected onAfterClose(): void {
        super.onAfterClose();

        // Clean up the element for the next dialog
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
    }

    // private _submit = () => {

    //     this.close();
    // }
}


package.json
{
  "name": "list-ext-react-dialog",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0 || >=18.17.1 <19.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "8.118.3",
    "@microsoft/decorators": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility": "1.18.2",
    "@pnp/sp": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7": "0.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.18.2",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}



